# Namespace in php application

Tags: namespaces, php-5.3

I am trying to manage my code in a sample code to learn. I have a sample application whose dir structure is as follow

```
-Sample
--bootstrap
--app
  --class1.php
  --class2.php
  --class3.php
--config
--public
--resource
--readme
```

Everything works fine for me, able to autoload the classes and consume all the feature. 
Now, I added namespace to my class definition.

```
namespace Sample\classes;
```

and my application won't work. In app needs I am trying to add

```
$obj = new Sample/classes/class1()  //no class found

use Sample/classes as Sample
```

but still class not found error

Any help to consume namespace in this setup will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need use backslash instead of slash

```
$obj = new Sample\classes\class1()
```